# Automatically timing every executed command and show in Bash prompt?

Tags: bash, time, prompt

I often happen to forget to explicitly prefix executions with the "time" command, ideally I would see in the next shell prompt how much real time the last command took (on every command).

I already scoured through the bash documentation, but couldn't find anything related.

Comment: This is a good question for Unix/Linux Stackexchange.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$ bind '"\C-j": "\C-atime \C-m"'
```

Or put this in your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\C-j": "\C-atime \C-m"
```

Then when you want to do `time sleep 1` you'd type `sleep 1` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I would not recommend swapping the `j` and `m` in the bind command (or in the .inputrc file). Every time you'd press <kbd>Enter</kbd> you'd get `time` added which could be pretty annoying and would cause errors when typing a multi-line command.

You could add this to your `~/.bashrc` to make the output of `time` more compact:

```
export TIMEFORMAT='r: %R, u: %U, s: %S'
```

(similar to my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/31845/is-there-a-way-to-configure-bash-to-always-page-output/31870#31870).)

Comment: Great, thank you! (sorry it took so long to reply)

Answer (score 12):

[Another stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862510/how-can-the-last-commands-wall-time-be-put-in-the-bash-prompt) covers the essentially the same question.  My answer in that thread can be summarized as:

```
trap 'SECONDS=0' DEBUG
export PS1='your_normal_prompt_here ($SECONDS) # '
```

...to display the number of seconds as an integer, or:

```
seconds2days() { # convert integer seconds to Ddays,HH:MM:SS
    printf "%ddays,%02d:%02d:%02d" $(((($1/60)/60)/24)) \
    $(((($1/60)/60)%24)) $((($1/60)%60)) $(($1%60)) |
    sed 's/^1days/1day/;s/^0days,\(00:\)*//;s/^0//' ; }
trap 'SECONDS=0' DEBUG
PS1='other_prompt_stuff_here ($(seconds2days $SECONDS)) # '
```

..for "Ddays,HH:MM:SS" with leading empty values removed.