# Bash: How can I subtract two time strings using bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I've crated the next script in order to find a lock file's age:

```
#!/bin/bash
now=`date +"%T"`
lock="aggregator.lock"
find . -name $lock -type f
if [ $? != 0 ];
        then
        exit
else
ls -ltrh $lock 2&>/dev/null
fi
if [ $? != 0 ];
        then
        locktime=`ls -ltrh aggregator.lock |awk -F" " '{print $7}'`
else
echo "File not found"
fi
```

I have two problems:

- The output of `ls -ltrh aggregator.lock |awk -F" " '{print $7}'`
  gives me the time in format HH:MM rather than HH:MM:SS and the output
  of `date +"%T"` gives me the time in format HH:MM:SS (As needed), so
  how can I get the modify time of the file with seconds?
- I don't know how to subtract between the times... I wanted to do something like `$now - $locktime` in order to get the seconds delta between both variables, how can it be done?

EDIT:
The meaning of the script is to find how long the lock file existed...
There's this script:

```
device0="/home/build/aggregator/scripts/aggregator.lock"
if [ -e "$device0" ]
then
echo process is allready running
else

touch $device0
java -Xms6g  -Xmx6g -jar /home/build/aggregator/aggregator-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
rm $device0
fi
```

Which creates the lock file... the only purpose of the creation of the lock file is to give me an indication about how long was the script's run time, just thought this information is needed as well, because I'm not looking for how much time passed since the last modification of the file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I edited my answer according to your edit. HTH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find out how much time ago a file was last modified, you can use

```
stat -c %Y file
```

To have the last modification date of the time in seconds since [the epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), and

```
date +%s
```

for the current date in the same units. Then simply subtracting them with `$(( ... ))` will give you the elapsed seconds since the last modification of file. Notice that Unix file system normally do not store the creation date, just the last access/change/modification date.

To convert back to a human-readable format, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/12199798/2907484

So basically:

```
now=$(date +%s)                          
was=$(stat -c%Y file)      
elapsed=$((now - was))
days=$((elapsed/86400))
hours=$(( (elapsed-days*86400)/3600 ))   
mins=$(( (elapsed-days*86400 - hours*3600)/60 ))
secs=$(( elapsed - days*86400 - hours*3600 - mins*60 ))
```

and now you can format the output with `echo` or  `printf` as you like

```
printf '%02dd:%02dh:%02dm:%02ds\n' $days $hours $mins $secs
```

will output

```
00d:18h:42m:27s
```

Probably the format `%02d` is not so appropriate for days --- but you got the idea. You can add weeks, years or whatever easily too.

To  see how much time a script/program use to run, you can use the bash builtin command `time` or the utility `/usr/bin/time` ([be sure to not confound them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434289/why-time-command-doesnt-work-with-any-option)), or you can follow the idea in this script by using:

```
was=$(date +%s)
...run your script...
now=$(date +%s)
```

and continue as above.

Comment: Nice, and then I'll be able to use `expr` to subtract, but then how will I get the answer in human readable format?

Comment: Don't use `expr` for math, use `$(())`. Nobody uses `expr` anymore, it has terrible syntax and can cause performance problems since it forks a separate process.

Answer (score 4):

If you have `stat` (which is part of the GNU coreutils package, so you should find it on any GNU/linux system), then you can get the modification time of a file directly in seconds:

```
stat -c%Y aggregator.lock
```

Consult `man stat` for a complete list of the data you can get about a file, and the corresponding format (`-c`) codes.

That lets you simply write, for example:

```
elapsed=$(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -c%Y aggregator.lock) ))
```

(`$(( ... ))` is bash-syntax for Arithmetic Expansion, see `man bash`)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do arithmetic, it's better to use Unix timestamps (number of seconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1970). Example using GNU `date`, but the same idea can be implemented using other versions.

```
now=$(date +%s)
locktime=$(date +%s --date 13:50:32)
diff=$(( now - lock time ))
```

Also, it's probably better to use `stat` to get the modification time of the lock file if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `find` output the timestamp right away, so try something like this:

```
locktime=$(find -maxdepth 1 -name aggregator.lock -printf '%T@')
now=$(date +%s)
delta=$(($now - $locktime))
printf "The file was modified %.0f seconds ago" $delta
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I then display the delta in human readable format?

Comment: The output of `locktime=$(find -maxdepth 1 -name aggregator.lock -printf '%T@')` is 1400166241.0000000000 rather than 1400166241 , how can it be fixed?

Comment: @ItaiGanot: now with rounding

Comment: Thanks @Wolph, I will not be able to check it until Sunday, I'll check it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited my script, and here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#file="/home/build/aggregator/scripts/aggregator.lock"
file="$1"

if [ -e "$file" ]; then 
    now=$(date +%s)                          
    was=$(stat -c%Y $file) 
    elapsed=$((now - was))
    echo $elapsed 
else
    echo 0
fi
```

Then from Zabbix I can run the script and get the number of seconds the file exists or "0" if the file doesn't exist:

```
[root@zabbix ~]# zabbix_get -s 10.200.X.X -k check.lock[/home/build/aggregator/scripts/aggregator.lock]
14
[root@zabbix ~]#
```

Thanks everyone for your solutions.