# Speed up rsync with Simultaneous/Concurrent File Transfers?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-12.04, rsync, simultaneous

We need to transfer `15TB` of data from one server to another as fast as we can. We're currently using `rsync` but we're only getting speeds of around `150Mb/s`, when our network is capable of `900+Mb/s` (tested with `iperf`). I've done tests of the disks, network, etc and figured it's just that rsync is only transferring one file at a time which is causing the slowdown.

I found a script to run a different rsync for each folder in a directory tree (allowing you to limit to x number), but I can't get it working, it still just runs one rsync at a time.

I found the `script` [here](http://www.krazyworks.com/making-rsync-faster/) (copied below).

Our directory tree is like this:

```
/main
   - /files
      - /1
         - 343
            - 123.wav
            - 76.wav
         - 772
            - 122.wav
         - 55
            - 555.wav
            - 324.wav
            - 1209.wav
         - 43
            - 999.wav
            - 111.wav
            - 222.wav
      - /2
         - 346
            - 9993.wav
         - 4242
            - 827.wav
      - /3
         - 2545
            - 76.wav
            - 199.wav
            - 183.wav
         - 23
            - 33.wav
            - 876.wav
         - 4256
            - 998.wav
            - 1665.wav
            - 332.wav
            - 112.wav
            - 5584.wav
```

So what I'd like to happen is to create an rsync for each of the directories in /main/files, up to a maximum of, say, 5 at a time. So in this case, 3 rsyncs would run, for `/main/files/1`, `/main/files/2` and `/main/files/3`.

I tried with it like this, but it just runs 1 rsync at a time for the `/main/files/2` folder:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define source, target, maxdepth and cd to source
source="/main/files"
target="/main/filesTest"
depth=1
cd "${source}"

# Set the maximum number of concurrent rsync threads
maxthreads=5
# How long to wait before checking the number of rsync threads again
sleeptime=5

# Find all folders in the source directory within the maxdepth level
find . -maxdepth ${depth} -type d | while read dir
do
    # Make sure to ignore the parent folder
    if [ `echo "${dir}" | awk -F'/' '{print NF}'` -gt ${depth} ]
    then
        # Strip leading dot slash
        subfolder=$(echo "${dir}" | sed 's@^\./@@g')
        if [ ! -d "${target}/${subfolder}" ]
        then
            # Create destination folder and set ownership and permissions to match source
            mkdir -p "${target}/${subfolder}"
            chown --reference="${source}/${subfolder}" "${target}/${subfolder}"
            chmod --reference="${source}/${subfolder}" "${target}/${subfolder}"
        fi
        # Make sure the number of rsync threads running is below the threshold
        while [ `ps -ef | grep -c [r]sync` -gt ${maxthreads} ]
        do
            echo "Sleeping ${sleeptime} seconds"
            sleep ${sleeptime}
        done
        # Run rsync in background for the current subfolder and move one to the next one
        nohup rsync -a "${source}/${subfolder}/" "${target}/${subfolder}/" </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    fi
done

# Find all files above the maxdepth level and rsync them as well
find . -maxdepth ${depth} -type f -print0 | rsync -a --files-from=- --from0 ./ "${target}/"
```

Answer (score 186):

Updated answer (Jan 2020)

`xargs` is now the recommended tool to achieve parallel execution. It's pre-installed almost everywhere. For running multiple `rsync` tasks the command would be:

```
ls /srv/mail | xargs -n1 -P4 -I% rsync -Pa % myserver.com:/srv/mail/
```

This will list all folders in `/srv/mail`, pipe them to `xargs`, which will read them one-by-one and and run 4 `rsync` processes at a time. The `%` char replaces the input argument for each command call.

Original answer using `parallel`:

```
ls /srv/mail | parallel -v -j8 rsync -raz --progress {} myserver.com:/srv/mail/{}
```

Comment: Note, if you customize your `ls` output through various means, such as the `LISTFLAGS ` variable or `DIR_COLORS` file, you may need to use `ls --indicator-style=none` to prevent `ls` from appending symbols to the path name (such as `*` for executable files).

Comment: I found this worked much better if I used     
cd /sourcedir ; parallel -j8 -i      rsync -aqH {} /destdir/{}   --    *

Comment: That's a placeholder for the filenames you get piped from the `ls` command before. `man parallel` should have more details. The `find` command uses the same I believe.

Comment: This is not an efficient solution, as shown here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189878/parallelise-rsync-using-gnu-parallel
This solution will create one rsync call per file in the listing

Comment: Depends on where your bottleneck is. When I used this command, I was limited in the bandwidth-per-connection. So using more memory for extra rsync instances was ok. Your use case may be different.

Comment: This answer was very helpful! I suggest adding `--sshdelay 0.2` just before `rsync` to make sure you don't overload the sshd on the remote server.

Comment: just tried: ls /srv/mail | parallel -v -j8 rsync -raz --progress {} myserver.com:/srv/mail/{}, which will generate sub dir with same name when sync dirs. And remove the last '{}', it works as expect .

Comment: what is use of -n (--max-args) arg here?

Comment: I would say that `parallel` is still a *much* better program than `xargs`. It's rarely preinstalled but it's always one of the first things I grab on a new machine.

Comment: @AdilSaju and @Prometheus The `-n` parameter of `xargs` limits how many arguments are given to each instance of `rsync`. Actually, it is redundant here, as using the -I option forces `xargs` into "one input line at a time" mode anyways.

Comment: What about hidden files , system files etc ? does ls cut it ?

Comment: @ManuelRiel
Great answer especially with the update!
Just wanted to add my two cents of using this approach; if your directory sizes are skewed then this will suffer as one stream can take forever to complete.
I solved it by recreating the dir tree on the remote first and then adjusting the streams based on skewness.

Comment: This will fail if you have spaces in your filenames: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758525/make-xargs-handle-filenames-that-contain-spaces

Comment: I have to cd source dir and excute `ls /source/files/ --indicator-style=none | xargs -n1 -P4 -I% rsync -Pa % 192.168.3.200:/target/files/
` and it work.

Comment: Interesting. `xargs` seems to be faster than `parallel`, but have fewer safety and order checks. See: [How do xargs and gnu parallel differ when parallelizing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62513178/4561887)

Answer (score 67):

Have you tried using [rclone.org](https://rclone.org)?

With `rclone` you could do something like

```
rclone copy "${source}/${subfolder}/" "${target}/${subfolder}/" --progress --multi-thread-streams=N
```

where `--multi-thread-streams=N` represents the number of threads you wish to spawn.

Comment: Fatal error: unknown flag: --multi-thread-streams

Comment: @StepanYakovenko I've tested the flag and it's working in version 1.55.1: 

`rclone copy killmouseaccel killmouseaccel2 --multi-thread-streams=4 --progress
2021/06/01 13:50:30 NOTICE: Config file not found - using defaults
Transferred:             0 / 0 Bytes, -, 0 Bytes/s, ETA -
Transferred:            1 / 1, 100%
Elapsed time:         0.0s`

Comment: Same to @Han.Oliver: The flag is working as I've pointed out in my last comment

Comment: Best option. Just run with 32 streams and its almost 50x faster than copying using finder or rsync.

Comment: what's the difference between `--multi-thread-streams` and `--transfers` ?

Comment: @soulmachine the first one spawns threads based on download chunks whereas transfers refers to the maximum number of simultaneous downloads that rclone can perform. With multi-thread-streams you can download one file splitting it into chunks that are downloaded concurrently. But if you are only downloading one file the --transfers option won't make any difference.

Comment: Building on the previous comments, you'll want to play with the number of `--transfers` allowed (the default seems to be 4) to speed up large copy operations with many files. I found something like `10` to be more reasonable.

Comment: Today I Learnt about `rclone` - Thank you so much I think this will do what I need. I need to copy tons of small files like 2MB but chunk them in parallel because of my lovely internet connection works better with multiple upload sockets instead of one. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest pairing this with `--max-size 200M` or whatever size works for you in testing and using rsync (possibly with xargs as above) to copy the larger files once that's done. rclone is much slower at copying each large file in my experience, when I was testing with large I got 40MB/s with rclone running many streams but over 200MB/s with rsync (with many small files rclone was still around 40MB/s while rsync dropped to around 5-10MB/s)

Comment: just to sum things up: use `--multi-thread-streams` when you download and use `--transfers` when you upload.

Answer (score 41):

`rsync` transfers files as fast as it can over the network. For example, try using it to copy one large file that doesn't exist at all on the destination. That speed is the maximum speed rsync can transfer data. Compare it with the speed of `scp` (for example). `rsync` is even slower at raw transfer when the destination file exists, because both sides have to have a two-way chat about what parts of the file are changed, but pays for itself by identifying data that doesn't need to be transferred.

A simpler way to run `rsync` in parallel would be to use [`parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). The command below would run up to 5 `rsync`s in parallel, each one copying one directory. Be aware that the bottleneck might not be your network, but the speed of your CPUs and disks, and running things in parallel just makes them all slower, not faster.

```
run_rsync() {
    # e.g. copies /main/files/blah to /main/filesTest/blah
    rsync -av "$1" "/main/filesTest/${1#/main/files/}"
}
export -f run_rsync
parallel -j5 run_rsync ::: /main/files/*
```

Comment: Doesn't seem I can get parallel on Ubuntu Server 12.04 with `apt-get install parallel`. Don't really want to start installing stuff manually just for this because it's very rarely going to be needed. I was just hoping for a quick script I could do it with.

Comment: @BT643: Use `apt-get install moreutils` to install `parallel`

Comment: @dragosrsupercool Thanks, will keep that in mind when I ever need to do anything like this in future :)

Comment: While yes copying single files go "as fast as possible", many many many times there seem to be some kind of cap on a single pipe where simultaneous transfers do not appear to choke each others' bandwidth thus meaning parallel transfers are far more efficient and faster than single transfers.

Comment: How to install parallel in Linux?

Comment: @PKHunter see @codesofthedark comment: `apt-get install moreutils`

Comment: could we modify this to use xargs -P? it's available by default usually.

Comment: Given that the answer links to the website for GNU `parallel`, it should be noted that the `moreutils` package installs a different binary with the same name. Both will accept the arguments given in this answer, but the GNU version should be installed with `apt-get install parallel` if you are reading the GNU documentation.

Comment: In other words, parallelism is never a good option when there is no network involved (disk to disk within the same machine for example)?

Comment: @Gaia depends on the hardware. do your own benchmarks.

Answer (score 35):

You can use `xargs` which supports running many processes at a time. For your case it will be:

```
ls -1 /main/files | xargs -I {} -P 5 -n 1 rsync -avh /main/files/{} /main/filesTest/
```

Answer (score 17):

## 3 - 4 tricks for speeding up rsync.

### 1. Copying from/to local network: don't use `ssh`!

If you're **locally** copying a server to another, there is no need to encrypt data during transfer!

By default, rsync use `ssh` to transer data through network. To avoid this, you have to create a *`rsync server`* on target host. You could punctually run daemon by something like:

```bash
rsync --daemon --no-detach --config filename.conf
```

where minimal configuration file could look like: (see `man rsyncd.conf`)

> ##### `filename.conf`
>
> ```
> port = 12345
> [data]
>        path = /some/path
>        use chroot = false
> ```

Then

```bash
rsync -ax rsync://remotehost:12345/data/. /path/to/target/.
rsync -ax /path/to/source/. rsync://remotehost:12345/data/.
```

#### 1.1. Minimal `rsyncd.conf` for restricting connection.

Regarding [jeremyjjbrown's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/914763/jeremyjjbrown) about security, here is a minimal config sample using ***dedicated network interfaces***:

[image: Rsync dedicated network]

Main public server:

```
eth0:  1.2.3.4/0          Public address Main
eth1:  192.168.123.45/30  Backup network
```

A 30bits network could hold only two hosts.

> ```
> ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━┯━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┯━━┓
> ┃ Netw. base │192.168.123.44 │     #0│11000000 10101000 01111011 001011│00┃
> ┃ Mask       │255.255.255.252│/30    │11111111 11111111 11111111 111111│00┃
> ┃ Broadcast  │192.168.123.47 │     #3│11000000 10101000 01111011 001011│11┃
> ┃ Host/net   │2              │Class C│                                 │  ┃
> ┠────────────┼───────────────┼───────┼─────────────────────────────────┼──┨
> ┃▸First host │192.168.123.45 │     #1│11000000 10101000 01111011 001011│01┃
> ┃ Last host  │192.168.123.46 │     #2│11000000 10101000 01111011 001011│10┃
> ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━┛
> ```

Backup server:

```
eth0:  1.2.3.5/0          Public address Backup
eth1:  192.168.123.46/30  Backup network
```

```bash
cat >/etc/rsyncd.conf <<eof
address 192.168.123.46
[main]
    path    = /srv/backup/backup0
    comment = Backups
    read only       = false
    uid     = 0
    gid     = 0
eof
```

So rsync will listen only on connection comming to `192.168.123.46` aka second network interface.

Then `rsync` is run from main server

```bash
rsync -zaSD --zc zstd --delete --numeric-ids /mnt/. rsync://192.168.123.46/main/.
```

Of course, adding some rule in your firewall could be not totally useless.

```bash
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 873 -j DROP
```

### 2. Using *zstandard* `zstd` for high speed compression

[Zstandard](https://facebook.github.io/zstd/) could be upto **8x faster** than the *common* `gzip`. So using this newer compression algorithm will improve significantly your transfer!

```bash
rsync -axz --zc=zstd rsync://remotehost:12345/data/. /path/to/target/.
rsync -axz --zc=zstd /path/to/source/. rsync://remotehost:12345/data/.
```

with maybe some `--exclude` directives (See at bottom of this answer!).

### 3. Multiplexing `rsync` to reduce inactivity due to  *browse* time

#### Two important remarks:

As this kind of optimisation is about disk access and filesystem structure. There is nothing to see with number of CPU! So this could improve transfer even if your host use single core CPU. If you plan
to use any *parallelizer* tool, you have to tell him to **not** consider
number of physical CPU.

As the goal is to ensure maximum data are using bandwidth while other task browse filesystem, the *most suited* number of simultaneous process depend on number of small files presents.

#### 3.1 [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script using `wait -n -p PID`:

Recent bash added a `-p PID` feature to `wait` builtin. Just the must for this kind of jobs:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

maxProc=3
source=''
destination='rsync://remotehost:12345/data/'

declare -ai start elap results order
wait4oneTask() {
    local _i
    wait -np epid
    results[epid]=$?
    elap[epid]=" ${EPOCHREALTIME/.} - ${start[epid]} "
    unset "running[$epid]"
    while [ -v elap[${order[0]}] ];do
        _i=${order[0]}
        printf " - %(%a %d %T)T.%06.0f %-36s %4d %12d\n" "${start[_i]:0:-6}" \
               "${start[_i]: -6}" "${paths[_i]}" "${results[_i]}" "${elap[_i]}"
        order=(${order[@]:1})
    done
}
printf "   %-22s %-36s %4s %12s\n" Started Path Rslt 'microseconds'
for path; do
    rsync -axz --zc zstd "$source$path/." "$destination$path/." &
    lpid=$!
    paths[lpid]="$path" 
    start[lpid]=${EPOCHREALTIME/.}
    running[lpid]=''
    order+=($lpid)
    ((${#running[@]}>=maxProc)) && wait4oneTask
done
while ((${#running[@]})); do
    wait4oneTask
done
```

Output could look like:

```bash
myRsyncP.sh files/*/*
```

```
   Started                Path                                 Rslt microseconds
 - Fri 03 09:20:44.673637 files/1/343                             0      1186903
 - Fri 03 09:20:44.673914 files/1/43                              0      2276767
 - Fri 03 09:20:44.674147 files/1/55                              0      2172830
 - Fri 03 09:20:45.861041 files/1/772                             0      1279463
 - Fri 03 09:20:46.847241 files/2/346                             0      2363101
 - Fri 03 09:20:46.951192 files/2/4242                            0      2180573
 - Fri 03 09:20:47.140953 files/3/23                              0      1789049
 - Fri 03 09:20:48.930306 files/3/2545                            0      3259273
 - Fri 03 09:20:49.132076 files/3/4256                            0      2263019
```

Quick check:

```bash
printf "%'d\n" $(( 49132076 + 2263019 - 44673637)) \
    $((1186903+2276767+2172830+1279463+2363101+2180573+1789049+3259273+2263019))
6’721’458
18’770’978
```

There was 6,72seconds elapsed to process 18,77seconds under upto three subprocess.

Note: you could use [musec2str](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72316403/1765658) to improve ouptut, by replacing 1st long `printf` line by:

```bash
        musec2str -v elapsed "${elap[i]}"
        printf " - %(%a %d %T)T.%06.0f %-36s %4d %12s\n" "${start[i]:0:-6}" \
               "${start[i]: -6}" "${paths[i]}" "${results[i]}" "$elapsed"
```

```
myRsyncP.sh files/*/*
   Started                Path                                 Rslt      Elapsed
 - Fri 03 09:27:33.463009 files/1/343                             0   18.249400"
 - Fri 03 09:27:33.463264 files/1/43                              0   18.153972"
 - Fri 03 09:27:33.463502 files/1/55                             93   10.104106"
 - Fri 03 09:27:43.567882 files/1/772                           122   14.748798"
 - Fri 03 09:27:51.617515 files/2/346                             0   19.286811"
 - Fri 03 09:27:51.715848 files/2/4242                            0    3.292849"
 - Fri 03 09:27:55.008983 files/3/23                              0    5.325229"
 - Fri 03 09:27:58.317356 files/3/2545                            0   10.141078"
 - Fri 03 09:28:00.334848 files/3/4256                            0   15.306145"
```

The more: you could add overall stat line by some edits in this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

maxProc=3  source=''  destination='rsync://remotehost:12345/data/'

. musec2str.bash # See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72316403/1765658

declare -ai start elap results order
declare -i sumElap totElap

wait4oneTask() {
    wait -np epid
    results[epid]=$?
    local -i _i crtelap=" ${EPOCHREALTIME/.} - ${start[epid]} "
    elap[epid]=crtelap sumElap+=crtelap
    unset "running[$epid]"
    while [ -v elap[${order[0]}] ];do  # Print status lines in command order.
        _i=${order[0]}
    musec2str -v helap ${elap[_i]}
        printf " - %(%a %d %T)T.%06.f %-36s %4d %12s\n" "${start[_i]:0:-6}" \
               "${start[_i]: -6}" "${paths[_i]}" "${results[_i]}" "${helap}"
        order=(${order[@]:1})
    done
}
printf "   %-22s %-36s %4s %12s\n" Started Path Rslt 'microseconds'
for path;do
    rsync -axz --zc zstd "$source$path/." "$destination$path/." &
    lpid=$! paths[lpid]="$path" start[lpid]=${EPOCHREALTIME/.}
    running[lpid]='' order+=($lpid)
    ((${#running[@]}>=maxProc)) &&
        wait4oneTask
done
while ((${#running[@]})) ;do
    wait4oneTask
done

totElap=${EPOCHREALTIME/.}
for i in ${!start[@]};do  sortstart[${start[i]}]=$i;done
sortstartstr=${!sortstart[*]}
fstarted=${sortstartstr%% *}
totElap+=-fstarted
musec2str -v hTotElap $totElap
musec2str -v hSumElap $sumElap
printf " = %(%a %d %T)T.%06.0f %-41s %12s\n" "${fstarted:0:-6}" \
   "${fstarted: -6}" "Real: $hTotElap, Total:" "$hSumElap"
```

Could produce:

```
$ ./parallelRsync Data\ dirs-{1..4}/Sub\ dir{A..D}
   Started                Path                                 Rslt microseconds
 - Sat 10 16:57:46.188195 Data dirs-1/Sub dirA                    0     1.69131"
 - Sat 10 16:57:46.188337 Data dirs-1/Sub dirB                  116    2.256086"
 - Sat 10 16:57:46.188473 Data dirs-1/Sub dirC                    0      1.1722"
 - Sat 10 16:57:47.361047 Data dirs-1/Sub dirD                    0    2.222638"
 - Sat 10 16:57:47.880674 Data dirs-2/Sub dirA                    0    2.193557"
 - Sat 10 16:57:48.446484 Data dirs-2/Sub dirB                    0    1.615003"
 - Sat 10 16:57:49.584670 Data dirs-2/Sub dirC                    0    2.201602"
 - Sat 10 16:57:50.061832 Data dirs-2/Sub dirD                    0    2.176913"
 - Sat 10 16:57:50.075178 Data dirs-3/Sub dirA                    0    1.952396"
 - Sat 10 16:57:51.786967 Data dirs-3/Sub dirB                    0    1.123764"
 - Sat 10 16:57:52.028138 Data dirs-3/Sub dirC                    0    2.531878"
 - Sat 10 16:57:52.239866 Data dirs-3/Sub dirD                    0    2.297417"
 - Sat 10 16:57:52.911924 Data dirs-4/Sub dirA                   14    1.290787"
 - Sat 10 16:57:54.203172 Data dirs-4/Sub dirB                    0    2.236149"
 - Sat 10 16:57:54.537597 Data dirs-4/Sub dirC                   14    2.125793"
 - Sat 10 16:57:54.561454 Data dirs-4/Sub dirD                    0     2.49632"
 = Sat 10 16:57:46.188195 Real: 10.870221", Total:                    31.583813"
```

#### Fake `rsync` for testing this script

Note: For testing this, I've used a *fake rsync*:

```bash
## Fake rsync wait 1.0 - 2.99 seconds and return 0-255 ~ 1x/10
rsync() { sleep $((RANDOM%2+1)).$RANDOM;exit $(( RANDOM%10==3?RANDOM%128:0));}
export -f rsync
```

### 4. Important step to speed up rsync process: avoid to slow him down!!

You could have to give some time to adequately configure the way you will avoid to synchronize useless datas!!

Search in man page for `exclude` and/or `include`:

> ```
>   --cvs-exclude, -C        auto-ignore files in the same way CVS does
>   --exclude=PATTERN        exclude files matching PATTERN
>   --exclude-from=FILE      read exclude patterns from FILE
>   --include=PATTERN        don't exclude files matching PATTERN
>   --include-from=FILE      read include patterns from FILE
> ```

For saving user directory, I often use:

```bash
rsync -axz --delete --zc zstd --exclude .cache --exclude cache  source/. target/.
```

Read carefully `FILTER RULES` section in man page:

```bash
man -P'less +/^FILTER\ RULES' rsync
```

#### 4.1 [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) Add an array of *cachedirs* at begin of your script:

Edit your `myBackupScript.sh` by doing something like this:

```bash
source=/path/to/sourceDir
mapfile -t -d '' cachedirs < <(
    find "$source" -type f -name CACHEDIR.TAG -print0 )
cachedirs=("${cachedirs[@]%/CACHEDIR.TAG}")
sed -e 1r<(declare -p cachedirs |
    fold -sw76 |
    sed 's/^declare -a //;s/^\[/\o11\[/;s/\[[0-9]\+\]=//g'
) -i myBackupScript.sh
```

This will *inline* edit your `myBackupScript.sh` for adding one array definition of a variable named *`$cachedirs`*, at line 2.

Then, in your script, you could add `"${cachedirs[@]/#/--exclude=}"` in your `rsync` command:

```bash
rsync -axz --delete --zc zstd "${cachedirs[@]/#/--exclude=}" \
    --exclude .cache --exclude cache source/. target/.
```

From there, you have keep in mind to **upgrade your *`$cachedirs`* array** when you add new applications...

... And/or upgrade them anyway periodically.

## Conclusion:

Read quietly man pages!! `man rsync` **and** `man rsyncd.conf` !!

Comment: "If you're locally copying a server to another, there is no need to encrypt data during transfer!"

That is a completely outdated attitude.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown Yes, but no!! There is a lot of case - using dedicated physical network for sample - where avoiding encryption will **significantly** reduce footprint **and** speedup transfert! Of course, you have to rightly configure your network, your *`rsyncd.conf`*  and maybe your firewall! But your comment are not absolutely right!

Comment: Then, months later, you plug in your air-grapped crypto wallet just to find all the $500,000 funds gone. How? Someone was sniffing the work network and saw the 16 words phrase transferred in plaintext via rsync. It has literally happened.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith If you configure your daemon to ***listen*** on a dedicated ethernet port ***not connected*** to internet, then this could not happen! For ensuring this, you could try yourself  to capture network packets on the internet part of your network!

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith It''s not ten months, I use this on public network, from more than twenty year ago, without any leaks!

Comment: This is a killer answer!  Thanks @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown answer upgraded, I've cited [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058544/speed-up-rsync-with-simultaneous-concurrent-file-transfers/72480364#comment134429790_72480364) ... (and add some suggest about firewall rules ;)

Answer (score 13):

There are a number of alternative tools and approaches for doing this listed arround the web. For example:

- The [NCSA Blog](https://wiki.ncsa.illinois.edu/display/~wglick/2013/11/01/Parallel+Rsync) has a description of using `xargs` and `find` to parallelize rsync without having to install any new software for most *nix systems.
- And [parsync](http://moo.nac.uci.edu/~hjm/parsync/) provides a feature rich Perl wrapper for parallel rsync.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: @i_m_mahii Stack Exchange should automatically keep a copy of linked pages.

Comment: parsync is awesome

Comment: Contrary to what some others may say, proposing a solution that is merely tools does help some of us. The "conform or go away!" crowd apparently doesn't actually just want to help others. so thanks for your post on behalf of all those who just discovered those two packages today from your post, and those who realized that xarg and find (without those packages) could also do the trick. Post and let the voters do their bit and ignore the bitter "get off my site" guys who seem to wander around here from time to time "enforcing".

Comment: Since many of us who are actually reading this particular post know what we're looking for already, and since the OP provided a detailed question, proposing an advanced use case here is appropriate. I don't want some generic example (as I shouldn't be copying and pasting it for my application anyway) as to how to use these tools; I'm going to read the docs and figure it out myself. Trust but verify.

Comment: Also disagree with the pedantic answer. Knowing which tools exist for this task solves 80% of the problem.

Answer (score 11):

I've developed a python package called: parallel_sync

https://pythonhosted.org/parallel_sync/pages/examples.html

Here is a sample code how to use it:

```
from parallel_sync import rsync
creds = {'user': 'myusername', 'key':'~/.ssh/id_rsa', 'host':'192.168.16.31'}
rsync.upload('/tmp/local_dir', '/tmp/remote_dir', creds=creds)
```

parallelism by default is 10; you can increase it:

```
from parallel_sync import rsync
creds = {'user': 'myusername', 'key':'~/.ssh/id_rsa', 'host':'192.168.16.31'}
rsync.upload('/tmp/local_dir', '/tmp/remote_dir', creds=creds, parallelism=20)
```

however note that ssh typically has the MaxSessions by default set to 10 so to increase it beyond 10, you'll have to modify your ssh settings.

Comment: Exception: The following command failed: find "./30mins" -noleaf -type f -name "*"

Comment: oh, wao. Just wao.

Comment: @max : could you allow the option to leave key blank? Say for people who connect thru VPN and don't use it

Comment: @user189035 sure. I just released 1.16 that should allow you to pass credentials without specifying any key. Let me know if you run into any errors.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest I've found is using background jobs in the shell:

```
for d in /main/files/*; do
    rsync -a "$d" remote:/main/files/ &
done
```

Beware it doesn't limit the amount of jobs! If you're network-bound this is not really a problem but if you're waiting for spinning rust this will be thrashing the disk.

You could add

```
while [ $(jobs | wc -l | xargs) -gt 10 ]; do sleep 1; done
```

inside the loop for a primitive form of job control.

Answer (score 4):

The shortest version I found is to use the `--cat` option of `parallel` like below. This version avoids using xargs, only relying on features of `parallel`:

```sh
cat files.txt | \
  parallel -n 500 --lb --pipe --cat rsync --files-from={} user@remote:/dir /dir -avPi

#### Arg explainer
# -n 500           :: split input into chunks of 500 entries
#
# --cat            :: create a tmp file referenced by {} containing the 500 
#                     entry content for each process
#
# user@remote:/dir :: the root relative to which entries in files.txt are considered
#
# /dir             :: local root relative to which files are copied
```

Sample content from `files.txt`:

```
/dir/file-1
/dir/subdir/file-2
....
```

Note that this doesn't use `-j 50` for job count, that didn't work on my end here. Instead I've used `-n 500` for record count per job, calculated as a reasonable number given the total number of records.

Comment: brevity is king

Answer (score 1):

I've found UDR/UDT to be an amazing tool. The TLDR; It's a UDT wrapper for rsync, utilizing multiple UPD connections rather than a single TCP connection.

References: https://udt.sourceforge.io/ & https://github.com/jaystevens/UDR#udr

If you use any RHEL distros, they've pre-compiled it for you... http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/admin/udr

The ONLY downside I've encountered is that you can't specify a different SSH port, so your remote server must use 22.

Anyway, after installing the rpm, it's literally as simple as:

```
udr rsync -aP user@IpOrFqdn:/source/files/* /dest/folder/
```

and your transfer speeds will increase drastically in most cases, depending on the server I've seen easily 10x increase in transfer speed.

Side note: if you choose to gzip everything first, then make sure to use --rsyncable arg so that it only updates what has changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/353383/parallelizing-rsync/368480#368480

```
#!/bin/bash
start_time=$(date +%s.%N)
# Transfer files in parallel using rsync (simple script)
# MAXCONN: maximum number "rsync" processes running at the same time:
MAXCONN=6
# Source and destination base paths. (not need to end with "/")
SRC_BASE=/home/user/public_html/images
DST_BASE=user@hostname.domain.local:/home/user/public_html/images
RSYNC_OPTS="-ah --partial"
# Main loop:
for FULLDIR in $SRC_BASE/*; do
    NUMRSYNC=`ps -Ao comm | grep '^'rsync'$' | wc -l `
    while [ $NUMRSYNC -ge $MAXCONN ]; do
        NUMRSYNC=`ps -Ao comm | grep '^'rsync'$' | wc -l `
        sleep 1
    done
    DIR=`basename $FULLDIR`
    echo "Start: " $DIR
    ionice -c2 -n5 rsync $RSYNC_OPTS $SRC_BASE/${DIR}/ $DST_BASE/${DIR}/ &
    # rsync $RSYNC_OPTS $SRC_BASE/${DIR}/ $DST_BASE/${DIR}/ &
    sleep 5
done

execution_time=$(echo "$(date +%s.%N) - $start" | bc)
printf "Done. Execution time: %.6f seconds\n" $execution_time
```

Answer (score -2):

using parallel rsync on a regular disk would only cause them to compete for the i/o, turning what should be a sequential read into an inefficient random read. You could try instead tar the directory into a stream through ssh pull from the destination server, then pipe the stream to tar extract.

Comment: the question does not invite an evaluation of a hypothetical scenario. the problem is stated as **saturating the available link** _given that there is_ or _presumably because there is enough_ IO capacity to do so.