# Status of the last instance of a parallelized function

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am looking to find a way to run a function in parallel and knowing exactly when all function instances finished.
I added a spinner (the instances of the function run a different time, depends on the variables, so i need to see something on the screen) and tried it the following way:

```
for a in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
    spin='/-\|'
    while true; do
        i=$(( (i+1) %4 )); printf "\r[ ${spin:$i:1} ] "; sleep .3;
    done & someFunction & 
    kill $!; trap 'kill $!' SIGTERM
done
```

But `someFunction` doesn't work. I assume because if it is fired as `someFunction &` it gets instantly killed by the next code line. And also the spinner keeps working forever on CLI after the script ends.

What is the way to run `someFunction` simultaneously, wait until the last instace finishes, and keep the spinner until then?

Comment: Take a look at `wait`.

Comment: You have to store `$!` **each** time and immediately after each use of `&`!! You could read a full sample at [Speed up rsync with Simultaneous/Concurrent File Transfers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72480364/1765658)

Comment: See [ProcessManagement - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) for excellent information about managing background processes with Bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way that Bash manages background processes there is usually a small chance that killing a process by PID will kill the wrong process.  If you are using Bash 4.3 (released in 2014) or later, try this kill-free code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

# FIXME: Define the 'args' array and the 'someFunction' function

# Run a spinner as a coprocess
coproc spinner \
{
    declare -r spin='/-\|'
    declare i=0
    while read -r -t 0.3 _; (( $? > 128 )); do
        printf '\r[ %s ] ' "${spin:i++%4:1}" >&2
    done
}

# Disown the spinner coprocess so 'wait' will not wait for it to exit
disown %% 

for a in "${args[@]}"; do
    someFunction "$a" & 
done

# Wait for all background processes (except the disowned spinner) to exit
wait

# Close the pipe to the spinner.  It will read EOF and close.
exec {spinner[1]}>&-
```

- Running the spinner as a [coprocess](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Coprocesses) makes it possible to stop it by closing its input pipe instead of killing it.  It also makes it possible to [disown](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-disown) the spinner process so [wait](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-wait) doesn't wait for it to exit.
- As described in the [read](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read) documentation, `read -r -t 0.3 _` will return with a status greater than 128 if it fails to read an input line in 0.3s.  Using `read` instead of `sleep` for the delay in the spinner saves resources by avoiding running a subprocess for every delay.
- `exec {spinner[1]}>&-` closes the (write end of) the pipe to the coprocess.  This will cause the `read` in the coprocess to return with a status less than 128, causing the coprocess to exit immediately.  Without the explicit close of the pipe the coprocess will continue to run until the top-level process exits (at which point the OS will close the pipe automatically).  (So the explicit close is unnecessary if the top-level process exits immediately after the `wait`, but I would do it anyway to allow for more code being added later (or the code being pasted into a bigger program).)
- `exec {spinner[1]}>&-` doesn't work in versions of Bash older than 4.3.  One way to work around the problem for versions of Bash back to 4.0 is to replace it with `eval "exec ${spinner[1]}>&-"`.  Use of `eval` is best avoided (see [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375)), but I don't know of an alternative that works for Bash 4.0 in this case.
- ALL_UPPERCASE variable names are best avoided because there is a danger of clashes with the large number of special ALL_UPPERCASE variables that are used in shell programming.  See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375).  That's why I replaced `ARRAY` in the original code with `args`.

Comment: I think disowning a process, just so you can group the other processes is bad practice. If someone wants to kill the cluster later, it will have wandered off on it's own. There's better ways to achieve this.

Comment: @xpusostomos, if the parent process exits for any reason then the pipe to the coprocess will be closed automatically and the spinner will stop.  It can't wander off on its own.

Comment: I see now what you're doing. Subtle.  Still... you're relying on the spinner process to be actually running properly in order to read, get EOF, then die of its own accord, whereas correctly, the operating system uses the child process mechanism to kill children even when they are frozen and misbehaving. And it's just not necessary to disown to solve this problem.

Comment: @pjh - despite all the rest of the given ways work after slight adaptation, i found yours more elegant and suitable. And it works as well (thanks!)
But there is an issue - whenever i try this piece of code on a small test function - works great. But when i do on a prod function - the function itself, spinning of a spinner works well, but in the end it throws  `exec: {spinner[1]}: not found` at the line of this error statement. Except this visual anoyance it works. And i wonder what is the reason for this error, what could be the impact, and how to detect the rootcause?

Comment: @faceless I don't know, but I would have thought the final exec {spinner[1]}>&- was superfluous because after that the process exits, and all file descriptors owned by a process are closed anyway when it exits. So removing that line seems like something to try.

Comment: @faceless, the `exec: {spinner[1]}: not found` message is probably due to using a version of Bash older than 4.3.  I've added a note that includes code that should work for versions of Bash back to 4.0.  The whole approach fails for versions of Bash older than 4.0 because they don't support coprocesses (or fractional timeouts with `read -t`).

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone is overthinking it a bit...

```
(
for a in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
    someFunction & 
done
wait
) &
GRP=$!
spin='/-\|'
while true
do
    i=$(( (i+1) %4 )); printf "\r[ ${spin:$i:1} ] "; sleep .3;
done &
SPINNER=$!
wait $GRP
kill $SPINNER
```

Comment: I gave the above as the simple correction to the original code. However I make the comment that it naievely assumes you won't hit ^C leaving the spinner going in the background. It would be a good idea to use bash "trap" to clean up in case the user hits ^C

Comment: It would also be good to use "test -t 1" to check if you are running on a TTY before outputting the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of processes you have forked off and then `wait` for them. The `wait` command is very flexible and can also wait for all background jobs at once (instead of one by one) or only for a specific job. See `man bash`, section `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS`. The following script starts a spinner that prints something every second and then forks off 5 processes which sleep for different amounts of time.

```bash
spinner() { for ((;;)); do sleep 1; printf '<spin>'; done; }
someFunction() { sleep "$1"; }

spinner &
spinner_pid="$!"
for ((i = 2; i < 12; i += 2)); do
  someFunction "$i"&
  function_pids["$!"]="$i"
done

while ((${#function_pids[@]})); do
  wait -n -p pid && echo -n  'finished: ' || echo -n 'failed: '
  echo "${function_pids[pid]}"
  unset 'function_pids[pid]'
done
kill -TERM "$spinner_pid"
wait -n "$spinner_pid" || :
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "**sleep 10**" with your program,

```
#!/bin/bash
  text='/-\|'
  delay=".5"

  spinner() {
    PID=$!
    echo "Please Wait..."
    while [ -d /proc/$PID ]; do
      for i in $(seq 0 3) ; do
        printf "\r[ ${text:$i:1} ]"
        sleep ${delay}
    done
  done
  }

 mainprogram()
 {
   sleep 10
 }

 mainprogram &
 spinner

 echo ""
```

Comment: Linux specific, not portable. Also fails to answer the question which is about launching a set of processes and monitoring them all.