Move large files(in GBs) in parallel
I have a use case, where we need to move large files from openshift to another server. Each files are in GBs. Total size of files were few Terabytes. I'm using oc rsync/cp feature to move files.But it's running on single process.
To run multiple process at a time, have used xargs command like below.
oc exec PODNAME -- bash -c "ls -d SOURCE_PATH/*/*.csv" print0 | xargs -I {} -P 8 oc rsync PODNAME:{} TARGET_PATH/

But i need to capture the exit status of each file transfer with logging. Entire process should wait for all command to execute. Any better way to restart only the failed files.
Note: We cant use GNU parallel due to restriction of policy.

I guess you mean concurrently no? Moving large file from one server to another should not result in any speed up in parallel since the NIC should be the bottleneck (unless slow compression is used or possibly slow encryption).

By the way, rsync seems to support this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058544/speed-up-rsync-with-simultaneous-concurrent-file-transfers

There is room for more network bandwith. It's under utilised. Thanks

Are you allowed to use Perl and shell scripts? In that case you can simply embed GNU Parallel in your own shellscript: parallel --embed > new_script.sh
