Fastest way to Transfer large amounts of Data from one remote server to another?
I have a remote server running with 500+gbs of data and i want to shift to a new remote server, what's the fastest way to transfer the data across them? Both are running ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 LTS respectively
I have tried using scp but it's giving me 11MB/s of peak transfer speed and I'm looking for a way to transfer it faster.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider this post with advice on using rsync
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72480364/1328439
Also this post https://superuser.com/q/353383

Rsync is a good option, especially if you want to be able to handle incremental updates, but if this is a one-off thing then sneakernet (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet) could be even faster.
