# Seconds to colon formatted time on Mac Terminal's zsh shell

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, zsh

##### Updated answer: simple solution with built-in `date` program on macOS.

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66928998/7299097.

```
$ date -ju -f "%s" 12345 "+%T"
03:25:45
```

Note: a drawback is that it does not support 86400 seconds or more (one day).

---

##### Original Question below.

The following post mentioned this is possible in *bash*, but apparently Mac's Terminal is different. So how should one convert an integer representing seconds into something like Day HH:MM:SS? I don't think I've come across an answer for Mac Terminal's *zsh* and macOS's `date`, `printf` program yet.

**Work for up to 23:59:59 in *bash*:**

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442175/7299097

```
$ TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%H:%M:%S)T\n' 12345
03:25:45
```

**Not so in *zsh* with Terminal on Mac:**

```
%  TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%H:%M:%S)T\n' 12345 
printf: %(: invalid directive
```

Even if you temporarily switch to *bash* like this:

```
% bash

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$ TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%H:%M:%S)T\n' 12345
bash: printf: `(': invalid format character
```

Also, `-d` on macOS is setting daylight saving time, apparently:

```
(in man date)
    -d _dst_  Set the kernel's value for daylight saving time...
```

What is a viable solution? If I don't install any packages from Homebrew, and I don't

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert seconds to hours, minutes, seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12199631); the [2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269811/7366100) mentions installing/using `GNU date` on MacOS, otherwise several other answers that may be of use ...

Comment: How about awk's `strftime`?

Comment: AIUI the `%(...)` format for `printf` was added in bash v4, but macOS only comes with v3.2.57. ccpizza's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199631/convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-seconds/66928998#66928998) (or the version in my comment) should work for in either shell for times up to 23:59:59; if the time might be more than that, you need one of the solutions that does the math.

Comment: @LMC I don't think macOS's awk support strftime.

Comment: @jackxujh: Why don't you simply split your H:M:S string on the colon, so that you get the individual numbers, and then do the multiplication using shell arithmetic?