Conditional printing one-liner
I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39452629/12038199
And modified it to this:
secs=88023
printf '%dh %dm %ds\n' $((secs/3600)) $((secs%3600/60)) $((secs%60))

The only problem I have with this is it would print 0 values. In example above: 1d 0h 27m 3s, I want to have 1d 27m 3s instead.
My question is it possible to have conditional values with printf or any other linux base tool. I know I can do if..else statements but I want one-liner.
I know in javasript you could do this:
console.log(`...${minutes === 0 ? '' : ` ${minutes}`}`)

There another solution using awk: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69984084/12038199
echo $secs | awk '{printf "%d %d %d", $1/3600, ($1/60)%60, $1%60}'


Boo, hiss re: wanting one-liners: In bash, where there are lots of pitfalls that are often best avoided by more explicit code, terseness is an actively harmful thing to prioritize. Much better to get in the habit of using functions: Doesn't matter if it's a 5-line function where it's defined if whenever you call it that's only one line.

(bash does support some kind of conditional expressions, but none are an exact match for what you want here: ${var+...} and ${var:+...} can only branch on whether a variable is empty or unset; $(( var ? a : b )) only works when all the values at hand are numeric in nature; it's a bit unfortunate that the question title here is vague enough that someone asking the question could be in a situation where either of those would apply, but in the immediate case at hand they don't)

There's no conditional logic in printf format strings.

It is kinda a funky nonstandard format. The standard is to print 00:27:03 as an ISO time string with that number of seconds. And the standard way to do that is with the date utility. Try: date -u -r 88023 +%T

while simple, there are many many cases to handle

Wrapping some 'bulky' bash code in a bash function:
secs2dhms() {
    local secs pfx values units i

    secs="$1"                                   # OP can add logic to validate input as needed
    pfx=""

    values=( $((  secs / 86400         ))       # days
             $(( (secs % 86400) / 3600 ))       # hours
             $(( (secs % 3600 ) /   60 ))       # minutes
             $((  secs % 60            )) )     # seconds
    units=( 'd' 'h' 'm' 's' )

    for ((i=0; i<=3; i++))
    do
        (( values[i] > 0 )) && {
            printf "%s%s%s" "${pfx}" "${values[i]}" "${units[i]}"
            pfx=" "
        }
    done

    [[ -n "${pfx}" ]] && echo ""                # terminate the series of printf calls
}

NOTES:

while this looks like a lot of code it is rather efficient in that it is 100% bash (printf and echo are shell builtins)
replacing the code with a comparable awk script ended up being ~40x times slower (when calling both functions 1000x times; main difference being the time to spin up 1000x instances of awk)
performance will be even worse for solutions that spawn subshells

Taking for a test drive with some one-liners ...
$ secs2dhms 23
23s

$ secs2dhms 3599
59m 59s

$ secs2dhms 3600
1h

$ secs2dhms 3601
1h 1s

$ secs2dhms 86401
1d 1s

$ secs=88023; secs2dhms "${secs}"
1d 27m 3s

$ secs2dhms 9936001
115d 1s

$ secs2dhms 9999023
115d 17h 30m 23s

OP can pipe the output to od -c to verify there is no trailing space.

yeah I benchmarked your code against my awk function - running it 1000x saves the user a total of 1.4 seconds

Use a function to hide code repetition:
secs=88023
maybe() { (($1)) && echo "$(($1))$2"; };
echo "$(maybe secs/86400 'd ')$(maybe secs%86400/3600 'h ')$(maybe secs%3600/60 'm ')$(maybe secs%60 s)"
# 1d 27m 3s

That's too long, nicer with some temps:
secs=88023
((d=secs/86400, h=secs%86400/3600, m=secs%3600/60, s=secs%60));
maybe() { (($1)) && echo "$(($1))$2"; };
echo "$(maybe d d\ )$(maybe h h\ )$(maybe m m\ )$(maybe s s)"

or with a loop:
secs=88023
((d=secs/86400, h=secs%86400/3600, m=secs%3600/60, s=secs%60));
maybe() { (($1)) && echo "$(($1))$1"; };
for i in d h m s; do maybe $i; done | paste -sd' '

same as above with crazy evil eval:
$ eval maybe' '{d,h,m,s}';' | paste -sd' '
1d 27m 3s

You could even:
secs=88023
((d=secs/86400, h=secs%86400/3600, m=secs%3600/60, s=secs%60));
printf "%s%s\n" $d d $h h $m m $s s | grep -v '^0' | paste -sd' '

There is %.*s in printf, but I am not happy with how *3 is needed to handle values 1 and 2.
secs=88023
((d=secs/86400, h=secs%86400/3600, m=secs%3600/60, s=secs%60))
printf "%.*s%.*s%.*s%.*s\n" $((d*3)) "${d}d " $((h*3)) "${h}h " $((m*3)) "${m}m " $((s*3)) "${s}s


all the answers with subshells ... ugh on performance; the last one (pure bash)  is 100x times faster (and about 3x faster than my answer); sooo, the last one is faster and a bit less code (especially if you wrap it in a function for easy use as a 'one-liner')

Why do you need *3 exactly in last example, I don't understand?

@sloppy try without *3 and see what happens. Then try *2 and see what hapens. Then try *9 and see what happens. printf format specifiers are documented in man 3 printf or https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf . It is needed, because in the case of d=1 there will be no "d " in the output.

You can pipe this to the end of your code to remove 0d, 0h, 0m, or 0s
sed 's, 0[a-z],,g'

$ printf '%dd %dh %dm %ds\n' $((secs/86400)) $((secs%86400/3600)) $((secs%3600/60)) $((secs%60))
1d 0h 27m 3s

$ printf ... | sed 's, 0[a-z],,g'
1d 27m 3s


Why pay the cost of spinning up a pipeline (fork()ing off a subshell for each component) and a copy of /usr/bin/sed (an execve() call, and then all the usual linking/loading/&c overhead) instead of doing this same thing with parameter expansions to keep it in-process? Benchmark this against markp-fuso's answer, and you'll see this one is much slower.

The in-process version of this logic looks like printf -v time_str ' %dd %dh %dm %ds\n' $((secs/86400)) $((secs%86400/3600)) $((secs%3600/60)) $((secs%60)) && time_str=${time_str// 0[[:lower:]]/} && time_str=${time_str# } && echo "$time_str" -- no pipelines and no external tools, so no fork cost and no exec cost.

Try this
    secs=88023

printf '%s%s%s%s\n' \
    "$( (( secs / 86400 )) && printf '%dd ' $(( secs / 86400 )) )" \
    "$( (( (secs % 86400) / 3600 )) && printf '%dh ' $(( (secs % 86400) / 3600 )) )" \
    "$( (( (secs % 3600) / 60 )) && printf '%dm ' $(( (secs % 3600) / 60 )) )" \
    "$( (( secs % 60 )) && printf '%ds' $(( secs % 60 )) )"

Tested in online sandbox : Online Sandbox

Doesn't work: The right-hand side values need to be numeric; you can't use a string in $(( )); as a numeric context, it tries to interpret all elements as integers.

See this failing in an online sandbox at https://ideone.com/WW5tNV

A bit bulky like @markp-fuso was warning, but works. Thanks!

Never mind, I just noticed there could be trailing space, for example when seconds 3600 = 1 hour

You should consider to add "minutes" in both cases.
Try this approach (putting days/hours/mins as variables to keep it clear):
secs=88023

days=$((secs/86400))
remain_secs=$((secs - (days*86400)))
hours=$((remain_secs/3600))
remain_secs=$((remain_secs - (hours*3600)))
mins=$((remain_secs/60))
remain_secs=$((remain_secs - (mins*60)))

[[ $days -gt 0 ]] && printf '%dd %dh %dm %ds\n' ${days} ${hours} $mins $remain_secs || printf '%dh %dm %ds\n' ${hours} $mins $remain_secs

