# How to execute script if program execution took more than x seconds

Tags: bash, unix

I want to get informed when long running command finished.

For example I need to get informed when `git pull` finish.
Right now I can use `git pull; tput bel` and terminal app will inform me that console require my attention.

Is it possible to execute `tput bel` for every command I enter in shell that was run more than 10 seconds?

I'm using tput bel as it works from local and remote ssh sessions.

Comment: See [Automatically timing every executed command and show in Bash prompt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176386/automatically-timing-every-executed-command-and-show-in-bash-prompt) and expand to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @RedX I found what I need. I ended up with adding this to my .bash_profile:

```
function timer_start {
  timer=${timer:-$SECONDS}
}

function timer_stop {
  timer_show=$(($SECONDS - $timer))
  if [[ $timer_show -ge '10' ]]; then
    tput bel
  fi
  unset timer
}

trap 'timer_start' DEBUG
PROMPT_COMMAND=timer_stop
```

This will execute `tput bell` and my terminal will bounce if it out of focus, every time my command was executed longer than 10 seconds.

Additionally you can add $timer_show to your PS1 to show duration in seconds of every command.